# Windows 7 VPC Beta mouse release

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

I am running Windows 7 RC and just downloaded the VPC Beta.  I've created a new VM and every time I click in it I can't get it to release my mouse.

What is the keystroke to get it to release?  I tried Left Alt, Right Alt and Both keys.  It seems to be different then in the previous version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that Windows 7 version of VPC (the VPC Beta) uses [Alt]+[CTRL]+[Left Arrow].

On previous versions of VPC the keys are [Right Alt] + [Enter] for full screen, and [Right Alt] + [Del] for [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[Del].

Answer (score 1):

Try right control, or control-alt